# Does taking limits change "$<$" into "$\le$"

Tags: limits, inequality

I saw this in my notes and didn't think much of it at the time of writing, but now I wanted to make sure this was/wasn't some property of limits no one ever told me about.

Let's say:

$L$ is a limit point of some sequence $S_n$ and each element of the sequence has the property that $s_n \in S_n \to s_n < 1$. Then when you take the limit for "$n$" does this become:

$$
s_n < 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} s_n \le 1
$$

or does it stay as

$$
s_n < 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} s_m < 1 \text{ ?}
$$

Thank you!!!

Comment: $\frac 1 n >0 \forall n$, but what is the limit?

Comment: Can you think of a sequence which converges to 1 but all the terms are $< 1$?

Comment: Taking a limit (if it exists) outputs a, well, limit. Generating points that may be part of a closed set is indeed a "property" of limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct. There's an for example $s_n=1-2^{-n}$ shows that the second is incorrect.

To see that it's correct you would use reductio ad absurdum. Assum that $\lim s_n=L>1$. Then there should for each $\epsilon>0$ exist an $N$ such that $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$, or $L-\epsilon<s_n<L+\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. Now select $\epsilon = (L-1)/2>0$, but $s_n < 1$ and $L-\epsilon = L - (L-1)/2 = {L+1}/2 > (1+1)/2 = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

You need $\le$. Take $s_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$.